Why is the assembly code generated with gcc under windows unable to be assembled under WSL?
I learned that assembly code doesn't depend on the OS. For verification, I generate the assembly code of the following code snippet (named test.c) under windows and try assembling it under WSL.
int add(int a, int b){
   return a+b;
}

After I run gcc test.c -S under windows, the file test.s is generated as
        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .globl  add
        .def    add;    .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .seh_proc       add
add:
        pushq   %rbp
        .seh_pushreg    %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
        .seh_endprologue
        movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
        movl    %edx, 24(%rbp)
        movl    16(%rbp), %edx
        movl    24(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
        .seh_endproc
        .ident  "GCC: (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 11.2.0"

If gcc test.s -c is run under windows, the object file test.o is generated without any error. However, if gcc test.s -c is run under WSL, the following errors are reported.
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:4: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.def'
test.s:4: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.scl'
test.s:4: Error: Missing symbol name in directive
test.s:4: Error: unrecognized symbol type "32"
test.s:4: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.endef'
test.s:5: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_proc'
test.s:8: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_pushreg'
test.s:10: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_setframe'
test.s:11: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endprologue'
test.s:19: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.seh_endproc'

Similarly, if I run gcc test.c -S under WSL, the generated file test.s can only be assembled under WSL.
I want to know the reason of it, and how to fix the reported errors.

What are the gcc versions in WSL and windows? Have you compared the output .s files? How do they look?

windows: gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 11.2.0 / WSL: gcc (Ubuntu 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2) 13.1.0

WSL is GNU/Linux, with ELF object files.  There are no .seh_ directives for ELF, only for Windows COFF/PE formats, because SEH (Structured Exception Handling) is a Windows thing.  The ELF equivalent is DWARF stack-unwind metadata in the .eh_frame section, created with .cfi_ directives.  So this is a case of assembly source code being target-specific even in the directives.  If you removed them, you could assemble a binary that tried to use the wrong calling conventions...

Assembly code does depend on the OS. It must be tailored to the ABI (application binary interface), which varies with the OS, dramatically so for Windows versus Linux. The calling convention is different, the layout of structures in memory is different, the basic object file format is different. What you tried to do cannot be expected to work.

@zwol: a lot of this has been hinted at/discussed in the linked to question. "Assembly language instructions are OS-independent" is the summary that OP should have maybe taken away from that and not "assembly code doesn't depend on the OS".

There is a difference in the assembly code generated on each OS. The main assembly instructions is the same regardless of OS, however each OS includes their own specific directives as needed. The errors are being produced by windows directives ('.def', '.scl', etc.) that aren't recognized by the Linux assembler. If you want to generate assembly code on windows and assemble it on Linux you could use a cross compiler. You can use MinGW-w64 in WSL to compile a windows .exe using the Linux compiler, and then you should have no errors.

The syntax for instructions doesn't depend on the OS, but the actual instructions needed to make a working program that calls libraries or makes system calls usually does depend on the OS.  e.g. symbol names and calling conventions.

WSL is GNU/Linux, with ELF object files. There are no .seh_ directives for ELF, only for Windows COFF/PE formats, because SEH (Structured Exception Handling) is a Windows thing.  (What are .seh_* assembly commands that gcc outputs?)
The ELF equivalent is DWARF stack-unwind metadata in the .eh_frame section, created with .cfi_ directives.  (What are CFI directives in Gnu Assembler (GAS) used for?)
So this is a case of assembly source code being target-specific even in the directives. If you removed them, you could assemble a binary that tried to use the wrong calling conventions...
The syntax for instructions doesn't depend on the OS, but the actual instructions needed to make a working program that calls libraries or makes system calls usually does depend on the OS. e.g. symbol names and calling conventions.
